# Is there a way to use Slack's API to get data on public workspaces?

Tags: api, slack, slack-api

I don't want to create a slack app, but I would like to write a script that - given a list of workspaces - can get the number of members in each workspace. These would be public workspaces like popular open source projects. I've tried combing the slack APIs but they are mostly geared around how to create slack applications as opposed to getting data like this. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that won't work. The Slack API requires you to first get a valid token for a workspace before you can get any information about, e.g. number of users. This usually happens by installing your Slack app, e.g. from the Slack Directory.